# Partial view not showing in the view in asp.net mvc4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, partial-views

I have created a view in which I want to show another Partial view. Below is my Code:

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult AddToCompare(string id)
    {
        var lst = db.CompareProduct.Where(p => p.CreatedDate.Year == DateTime.Now.Year && p.CreatedDate.Month == DateTime.Now.Month && p.CreatedDate.Day == DateTime.Now.Day).ToList();
        return PartialView(lst);
    }
```

**View.cshtml**

```
<p class="compare">
        @Ajax.ActionLink("Add To Compare", "AddToCompare", new { id = Model.ProductId }, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "CompareList" })
    </p>
    <div id="CompareList" class="clear">
        Compare List
    </div>
```

I have also referenced **jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js** in my view but when i click on the above link it opens the partial view in new page instead of showing it into the same view.

Am I doing something wrong? Please help me.

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the all the help.

I found another way to show the Partial View. I just add a jquery function and call it on the onClick event. Below is the code if anybody needs.

**jQuery function**

```
function getView() {
     $('#CompareList').load("@Url.Action("AddToCompare", "Product", new { id = Model.ProductId })");
}
```

**Calling Link**

```
<a href="JavaScript:void(0)" onclick="getView()">Add To Compare</a>
```

It worked like a charm !!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe its becouse  your js files should be the next format

```
1 jquery
2 jquery.unobstrusive
3 jquery.unobstrusive-ajax
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. but I have referenced all the 3 js files in head tag in _Layout.cshtml file. But still it is not working.

Comment: add new field in ajaxoption: InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace